# drill down windows phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I created a chart in windows phone app using AmChart.I want to put the select value in the chart in a textbox How Can I do this?

This my code (Xaml) so far:

```
    <!--ContentPanel - placez tout contenu supplémentaire ici-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <amq:SerialChart x:Name="MainPage1"  DataSource="{Binding Data}" CategoryValueMemberPath="axis"
 AxisForeground="White"
 PlotAreaBackground="Black"
 GridStroke="DarkGray"  >
            <amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
                <amq:ColumnGraph ValueMemberPath="value" Title="Column #2" Brush="#8000FF00" ColumnWidthAllocation="0.4" />
            </amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
        </amq:SerialChart>
        <amq:PieChart x:Name="Pie" DataSource="{Binding Data}" TitleMemberPath="axis" ValueMemberPath="value"/>
                  <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="184,326,-184,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"/>

    </Grid>



</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following `library` allows you to create charts easily in Windows Phone..

Take a look over [here](https://github.com/ailon/amCharts-Quick-Charts)